# Console not showing Mac OS app sandbox violations in Apple's Quick Start

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I'm stepping through [this Apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html) for enabling sandboxing. I've successfully worked through the sections, creating the Xcode project, enabling app sandbox, creating a certificate, specifying the code signing identity and confirming that the app is sandboxed.

When I then try and diagnose the intentional violation, nothing appears in Console like the guide describes. Enable App Sandboxing is ticked but nothing underneath it is (e.g. Allow Outgoing Connections). The entitlements file suggests sandboxing is enabled, the app isn't showing the Apple website and Activity Monitor says the app is sandboxed.

I'm using `Console.app`, looking at All Messages (as described in the **To diagnose an App Sandbox violation** section of the tutorial). I'm expecting to see messages from `sandboxd`, but don't see anything related to sandboxing. The application itself behaves exactly as described in the tutorial, showing the Apple website when not sandboxed, and then not showing it when sandboxed.

I'm on Mac OS 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.1. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you have successfully sandboxed your app, but your problem is that you can't see the errors being logged. Can you provide more detail on how you're looking for the errors, what you're expecting to see, and what you are (or aren't) actually seeing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm using Console (in /Applications/Utilities) and looking at All Messages (as described in the 'To diagnose an App Sandbox violation' section of the tutorial). I'm expecting to see messages from sandboxd, but don't see anything connected to sandboxing. The application itself behaves exactly as described in the tutorial, showing the apple website when not being sandboxed, and then not showing it when being sandboxed.

Comment: Thanks for that additional info. I added it to your question for you, as it might help solicit solutions from other people. I personally don't have an answer, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this as well on 10.9.2 with Xcode 5.1, but I'm pretty sure the OS and Xcode version are irrelevant these days (might matter if you're on something as old as 10.5). In my case the actual `/var/log/system.log` file will still show the `sandboxd` messages, but they would not show up in the "**All Messages**" query, and so I could not access the "**Full Report**" button talked about in the tutorial.

On my particular machine, I did find out that if I logged in as my admin user (I have two users on my system, normal and admin/root), I could see the log messages in "All Messages", which let me be able to inspect the sandboxd messages and find out they're being sent with UID=0. I'm not sure how that is controlled (why does it only affect us, but everyone else is fine?), but apparently the Console will not show messages in the system log that were sent to/by root if you aren't root yourself.

This leads to a hacky solution: Launch your Console as root.

To do that, in the terminal type:

```
sudo -b /Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console
```

And now you should be able to use that Console to see all of the messages.

--

While figuring this out, I did go down a dead end trying to figure out how logging config files might be hurting me. They turned out to be irrelevant for me, but they might end up helping you:

Investigation found [this thread](http://www.windowslinuxosx.com/q/answers-mac-asl-unable-to-see-my-applications-log-messages-232677.html) where someone was experiencing what seemed like similar issues and looked like the cause was filtering in `/etc/asl.conf` or `/etc/syslog.conf`

I also found Apple's Documentation on logging and filtering [Logging Errors and Warnings: Messages are filtered](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/LoggingErrorsAndWarnings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW8-SW9)

You might need to look into messing with the .conf files if you can't see the sandboxd messages in your /var/log/system.log, but if you can see them there then your issue is probably unrelated to them. In my case they were a dead end and I spent a few hours going down this route before stumbling on the "launch as root" solution.